# Ordering without repetition

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many ways can I  list a $0$’s and b $1$’s in ways such that that no consecutive $0$’s appear?

I believe it relates to the binomial coefficient, but I'm having trouble seeing exactly how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go about it like this.  First, you must specify that $b\ge a-1$.  If you have three 0's, you would need at least two 1's.

With that, you can imagine laying out all the $1$'s with a space between each one and a space on each end.  So now you have $b+1$ spaces to place $a$ objects.

Comment: so it is (b+1+a) choose a?

Comment: Just (b+1) choose a.